# iOS design not full screen on simulator

Tags: ios

I'm having an issue with the simulator not showing full screen. It was working. I have not made any changes. I'm not sure why it looked like this now. I've checked the constraints and settings, it will not go beyond the right or bottom blank spaces. Please help

[iOs not full screen on Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvd3g.png)

Comment: can you show constraint with view ?

Comment: send your storyboard or xib file.